# Quantifying Files in a Large Archive with PHP

Tags: php, php-ziparchive, phar

### What I would like to do

I'm working with archives (zip and tar formats) which vary between 1 GB and 5 GB in size. Each archive contains tens of thousands of files; at times more than 100,000 files. These files are spread throughout various nested directories.

I am trying to determine, accurately, how many files are within a given archive (tar or zip) without having to extract the contents of the archive, or (if I can avoid it) loading the entire archive into memory all at ones. If there's a streaming option, that would be wonderful.

### What I have tried

For zip archives, this seems to be fairly straight-forward:

```php
$archive = new ZipArchive;
$archive->open( "archive.zip" );
$archive->count(); // Or, alternatively, $archive->numFiles;
```

This gets a bit more difficult when dealing with tar archives, however. There is a nice method for handling both types of archives in the `PharData` class, but it doesn't report more than 65535 files.

```php
$archive = new PharData( "archive.tar", Phar::TAR );
$archive->count();
```

In addition to the above, I have also tried the `phar://` protocol, recursively quantifying the number of files within a directory and its children. This too, however, doesn't appear to work as reliably as `ZipArchive::count`:

```php
$path = "archive.zip";
$phar = "phar://$path";

function count_files ( $dir ) {
    $total = 0;
    if ( $handle = opendir( $dir ) ) {
        while ( false !== ( $file = readdir( $handle ) ) ) {
            if ( in_array( $file, [ ".", ".." ] ) ) {
                continue;
            }
            if ( is_dir( $dir . "/" . $file ) ) {
                $total += count_files( $dir . "/" . $file );
            } else {
                $total += 1;
            }
        }
        closedir( $handle );
    }
    return $total;
}
```

In the above, `count_files( $phar )` returns 60,115 while `ZipArchive::count` returns 105,497.

To further complicate things, when the archive is extracted, Windows Explorer (via the folder properties) states there are 96,525 files (and 8,972 folders) (*Update: `count_files` also says 96,525 when given the extracted archive directory*). This amount is not the same as either results in the above examples. When I attempt to quantify the number of files (in the extracted directory) with PowerShell, I get yet another unique result: 96,498 (27 fewer than was reported by Windows' Shell):

```
(Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File | Measure-Object).Count
```

### Environmental Details

I'm testing this on Windows 10, with PHP 8.0.0 (cli) (NTS Visual C++ 2019 x64)

Comment: @oguz-ismail, why did you remove the `PharData` tag? It's very relevant to the question, is it not?

Comment: I don't think a separate tag for it is necessary. It didn't even have a tag excerpt anyway